# Proof of a result on closed subgroups of Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $M\supseteq K$ be an algebraic normal extension. Then its Galois group is profinite. I have been told that in this hypothesis, if $H\leq G$, then $H''=H\iff \bar H=H$, where $H'=\mathrm{Fix}(H)=\{\alpha\in M:\alpha^g=\alpha\,\,\forall g\in H\}$ and $H''=\{g\in G:\alpha^g=\alpha\,\,\forall\alpha\in H'\}$, and finally $\bar H$ is the topological closure of $H$ in $G$, which makes sense since $G$ is a topological space. I was wondering where I could find a proof of this. I would have tried googling, but the best query I could think of was **topological closure of subgroup of Galois group and coincidence of it with the subgroup tha fixes all elements fixed by all of the group** which is definitely too long to produce any sensible result with GOogle. So I came here to ask. Does anyone know a good reference available online (please avoid Google Books)? Or could someone write a proof in an answer? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that $G = \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/K)$ is profinite, you know that the open subgroups are exactly those of the form $\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)$ where $L/K$ is a finite subextension of $M/K$. I'll now prove the statement:

> For any subextension $L/K$ of $M/K$, the subgroup $\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)\leq G$ is closed.

Proof: Choose any $\sigma\in G - \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)$. We'll show there is an open neighbourhood of $\sigma$ in $G$ which does not meet $\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)$, so that the complement of $\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)$ is open in $G$. Let $\alpha\in L$ be such that $\sigma\alpha \neq \alpha$, possible because $\sigma$ by definition does not fix $L$. Set $H = \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/K[\alpha]) \leq G$, which is open as $K[\alpha]/K$ is a finite extension. For any $h\in H$, $\sigma h(\alpha) = \sigma\alpha\neq \alpha$, so $\sigma H\cap \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)$ is empty and $\sigma H$ is the desired open neighbourhood of $\sigma$. $\square$

The following is essentially the converse to the above statement:

> If $H\leq G$ is closed, then $H = \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H))$.

Proof: The inclusion $H\leq \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H))$ follows from the definition of fixing field. As $H\leq G$ is closed, $G - H\subseteq G$ is an open subset. By the definition of the profinite topology, for any $\sigma\in G - H$, there exists a finite extension $L/K$ such that $\sigma\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)\subseteq G - H$. Thus, $\sigma\notin H\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)$. By enlarging $L$ (shrinking $\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)$), we may assume that $L/K$ is finite Galois. Let $H|_L\leq \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(L/K)$ be the image of $H$ under the canonical isomorphism
  $$\phi:\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/K)/\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)\to \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(L/K).$$
Similarly, the restriction $\sigma|_L\in \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(L/K)$ of $\sigma$ to $L$ is the image of $\sigma$ under $\phi$. As $\sigma\notin H\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)$, $\sigma|_L\notin H|_L$, so there is $\alpha\in \mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H|_L)$ (fixed field of $H|_L$ inside $L$) such that $\sigma|_L(\alpha) = \sigma(\alpha)\neq \alpha$. As $\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H)\supseteq \mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H|_L)$, this shows that $\sigma\notin \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H))$. Thus, $G - H\subseteq G -  \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H))$. $\square$

Now, let's prove the statement you're asking about:

> If $H\leq G$, then $\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H)) = \overline{H}$.

Proof: By our first statement, $\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H))\leq G$ is closed. As $H\leq \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H))$, this shows that $\overline{H}\leq \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H))$.

As $H\leq \overline{H}$, we have $\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H)\supseteq \mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(\overline{H})$, so $\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H))\leq \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(\overline{H}))$. By the second statement, $\overline{H} = \mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/\mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(\overline{H}))$, which gives the other inclusion. $\square$

Comment: I am afraid I do not know what the profinite topology is nor why your first statement holds. Keep in mind that these things were done in an hour as a "bonus", in a not-too-rigorous-or-precise manner. What do you mean by "finite Galois [extension]"?

Comment: Oh, and "the statement I'm asking about" would be both implications :). Just a note.

Comment: Actually, the last statement doesn't seem to be my question. What I'd like to prove is that a subgroup $H\leq G$ is closed iff it is equal to $\operatorname{Gal}(M/\operatorname{Fix}(H))$. The penultimate statement is one implication, namely closed => coincides with etc., but the other implication?

Comment: @MickG The other implication is the first statement, because $\mathop{\mathrm{Gal}}(M/L)$ is closed for $L = \mathop{\mathrm{Fix}}(H)$.

Comment: @MickG The "profinite topology" just means that the open subgroups are exactly the ones of finite index.

Comment: @JanLadislavDussek why is  $L|k$ necessarily a finite extension?